# Set div width using percentage without limiting to parent div width

Tags: css

Hello I have something like this in my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image-slider"></div>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.container {
        max-width: 1133px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
```

I want to set the div width of .image-slider to 100% but here is the catch, instead of following the 100% width of the container which is only 1133px, I want it to follow the 100% width size of my body tag. Of course one solution is to put the image-slider out of the container but since this is a wordpress site, that kind of solution is not that easy to do in some complicated themes. Is there a way to make the .image-slider width 100% following the size of the body tag without putting it out of the container wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

Positioning the div.image-slider absolute will take it out of the normal flow of the document, and its position will be relative to the first parent tag with a relative position.

```
body{
  position: relative;
}
.image-slider{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```